# Form not displaying error messages for nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble getting error messages to display when a user tries to submit a blank comment. Upon create failure it `render 'posts/show'` properly but it doesnt appear to be sending the `@comment` object that my error_messages partial expects. Any thoughts?

comments_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      @comments = @post.comments.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 5)
      render 'posts/show' # => Renders but does not display errors???
    end
  end
```

posts_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    @comment = @post.comments.build if signed_in?
  end
```

_comment_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], :html => { :role => "form" }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :content %>
        <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter new comment..." %>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try using `<%= form_for([@post, @comment], :html => { :role => "form" }) do |f| %>`, because you already having @comment in your create and I believe in show action as well.

Comment: Wow - staring right at me the whole time. Thank you!

Comment: Glad, it worked, I have added my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], :html => { :role => "form" }) do |f| %>
```

This always creates a form for blank comment object. So After create action, it does the same and that's why you are not getting any errors.

As you already done the initialization for the `@comment` in your `create` action, so you can use that in the form to get the error message for that `@comment` object. And I believe you have initialized the `@comment` object in your `show` action as well to work the partial form for both the `show` and `create` action.

So try using the following

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment], :html => { :role => "form" }) do |f| %>
```